# Android: retrofit file corrupted

Tags: android, pdf, retrofit2

I cannot open the pdf file I downloaded from the internet on my android device.
It gives the error that the file is corrupt. (corrupt file opens in pc)

```
//Request;
@GET("url")
suspend fun getDocumentDownload(@Path("File") file: String?): Response<ResponseBody>
```

---

```
//writeResponseBodyToDisk
var inputStream: InputStream? = null
var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
val byteArray = ByteArray(4096)
val fileSize = body.contentLength()
var fileSizeDownloaded: Long = 0
inputStream = body.byteStream()
outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
while (true) {
    val read = inputStream.read(byteArray)
    if (read == -1) {
        break
    }
    outputStream.write(byteArray, 0, read)
    fileSizeDownloaded += read.toLong()
}
outputStream.flush()
```

---

Response corrupt;
[image]
Response success;
[image]

Comment: `I tried different pdf's but they were ok.` If only one of the files you tried is corrupt then what is the conclusion?

Comment: What can we see on those pictures?